# Zookeeper Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, ubuntu-18.04

according to this link : https://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/2016/12/07/how-to-setup-and-run-multiple-zookeeper-instances-on-one-box/

we can setup zookeeper multiple instance on single node. as far as i know, the best way is create multiple instance zookeeper on multi nodes to avoid single point of failure. i just want to know what's the benefit if we create multiple instance zookeeper on single node. many thanks before.

Regards,
Steven

Comment: It costs less :) But as you mentioned it is not suggested for production environments.

Comment: is there any benefit besides cost ? :D

Comment: let's say i have 3 zookeeper instances in 3 different nodes and 2 kafka broker in 2 different nodes, can i point to 1 zookeeper and 1 kafka broker to create topic and then it will replicate to other kafka broker and zookeeper so that consumer will not confuse setting which kafka broker they will listen ?